# How to push current Cloud Source Repository using the attached Cloud Build Trigger to another Cloud Source Repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-source-repos, cloudbuild.yaml

I have this Cloud Source Repository that has a trigger that builds the docker file and pushes to Cloud Container Registry. I want to be able to push this repo to another Cloud Source Repository from a step in the build file. But I get the following error:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/git
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

This is my build config file:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${REPO_NAME}:${SHORT_SHA}", "."]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/${REPO_NAME}"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git"
    args: ["push", "--force", "https://source.developers.google.com/p/${_DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT}/r/${_DOWNSTREAM_REPO}", "master"]
```

Comment: http error code 500 = "internal error": the server you contacted tripped, fell over, and yelled "help". It's a problem *over there*, so go over there (or send the medics over there) to fix it over there. ("There" is either gcr.io or google.com, I assume.)

Comment: It is google.com in this case ...

Comment: Perhaps Google were being DDoS-ed at the time. If it's repeatable and there are no reports of attacks going on, you should poke someone at Google about it.

Comment: Hi @George Udosen, I have posted an answer. Have you seen that? And did it help you?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try pushing only 5-10 commits at once which might help.
2. I would like to suggest you to make some changes to your github configuration by increasing the Git buffer size to the largest individual file
   size of your repo:

   `git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400`